# Nuxt 3 Static Generation (nuxt generate) Not Handling ~/server/api Routes

Tags: nuxt.js, nuxt3

I'm developing a Nuxt 3 application that's primarily static content, but I have a form submission that interacts with Pipedrive CRM. In development (`npx nuxi dev`), everything works perfectly. The problem arises when I try to statically generate the site using `nuxt generate`.

Here are the specifics:

I have a form component that, upon submission, calls a function `sendPipedriveLead` from a composable (~/composables/pipedrive.ts).

The function in the composable makes an await $fetch call to the route `/api/createLead`.

The server-side logic for this route is housed in `~/server/api/createLead`. This follows Nuxt's new directory structure where server-side routes can be created using files inside `~/server/api`. Within that route/file, we do the rest of the magic, including another $fetch to Pipedrive's API URL.

When running in development mode, I can see the server handle this route correctly. It all works perfectly there. However, after running `npx nuxi generate --dotenv .env.local` then `npx serve .output/public` (basically `nuxt generate`) and serving the static files (`npx serve .output/public`), I get a 404 error when submitting and attempting the `/api/createLead` route.

The error is as follows:

```
HTTP 10/5/2023 3:33:20 PM ::1 POST /api/createLead
HTTP 10/5/2023 3:33:20 PM ::1 Returned 404 in 1 ms
```

From my understanding, the `~/server/api` directory is used for server-based routes, accessible only when there's an active server running. Given that `nuxt generate` produces a fully static site without an active server, it seems like these routes are not accessible post-generation. Is that the case?

How can I maintain my server-side route functionality for form submission while still leveraging the performance benefits of `nuxt generate` for the rest of my site? Is there a recommended approach to handle this kind of scenario in Nuxt 3?

Answer (score 1):

I faced a similar issue but with shared hosting it didn't work, If you are using shared hosting and not need to fix reverse proxy or .htaccess file. So i moved that project to VPS there serve.

If the case is you need to access the public folder content this also failed. I will share you the [discord](https://discord.com/channels/473401852243869706/1181145756619522070/1189395657614688316) thread when this thing is discussed in detail I solved it using the api route.